# Software for GUI implementation using LPC2478?

Tags: embedded

Is there any software that helps me to implement GUI in LPC2478 microcontroller?

Is embOS compatible with LPC2478?

Comment: Such questions tend to depend mostly on available memory resources, specific display type, and functional requirements much more than they do on the type of chip - unless there's a requirement for an MMU which a given chip may or may not have.  Likely you can ask a better question after doing more research and clarifying your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NXP LPC24xx is an ARM7TDMI core part.  The question of whether [Segger embOS](http://www.segger.com/embos.html) is supported for this target is best answered by consulting the [vendors support information](http://www.segger.com/embos-ports.html) (the answer is "yes" BTW).

However embOS is an RTOS not a GUI and while that may be helpful in presenting a GUI on a real-time application, it does not in itself provide a GUI.  Segger do however have a GUI product - [emWin](http://www.segger.com/emwin.html) - which can be used with or without an RTOS, and independent of embOS.  The issue there perhaps is whether your particular display device is [supported](http://www.segger.com/emwin-display-drivers.html), although it is possible to develop your own or use the microcontroller to [control the LCD directly](http://www.segger.com/cpu-mcu-driver.html).

Either way embOS and emWin are commercial products with good documentation and excellent vendor support - you would do just as well to ask your questions at info@segger.com.

Note that if you use [Keil MDK-ARM Professional](http://www.keil.com/arm/selector.asp), then Segger emWin is included royalty-free.